# I'm currently creating my first Windows Device Driver "Hello world." activity. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

Tags: c++, windows, driver

How do I generate a .sys file so that I can load it in the OSRloader?

Answer (score 3):

A .sys file is basically a .dll file that only depends on the kernel.

You'll need the Windows Driver Kit's libraries (especially `ntoskrnl.lib`).
Open up the project properties and:

1. Select Linker->Input, then change *Ignore All Default Libraries* to *Yes*.
2. Select Linker->Input, then add `ntoskrnl.lib` to *Additional Dependencies*.
3. Select Linker->System, then change *Driver* to to *Driver*, and *Subsystem* to *Native*.
4. Select Linker->Advanced, then change *Entry Point* to *DriverEntry*.
5. Select Linker->Advanced, then change *Image Has Safe Exception Handlers* to *No* (if it's there).

Do these for *both* Debug *and* Release configurations (you might not be able to use the Debug build).

Then build. You may also need to add other libraries (e.g. `BufferOverflowK.lib`).